# Why are there chips in tile glazing along one side of a cut?

Tags: tile, cutting

I am using a [table saw](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1247344/Mastercraft-055-6740-2.html?page=10) which I modified to cut 24" tiles by replacing the sliding bars with those of a Qep 24" slim line model.
Update: The above is the Canadian model. Here is a video showing the US model (working and looking almost the same -funny the picture on the box shows it used the WRONG way! The guy in the video explains why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyAy5qS638I&ab_channel=GaryLindgren

So the device is now working but it is my first ever tile wet cut. Previously I used the Qep device to cut the same tiles and I was disappointed (posted around here about it)

So here are two pictures of the first cut
The larger piece was closer to the user and I was holding it with my hand
The narrower one was on the other side of the blade and it looks chipped in same areas. Are there any technical explanations for the differences between the two sides of the same cut ? Is this normal ?

[image]

and a close up of the cut

[image]

Updates:
here is what the tile saw looks like
[image]
And here is my understanding of what is happening based on various replies
[image]

Comment: Did you look for one (or more) bad teeth on the bad side?  Misaligned, dull, etc?  Photos of how you replaced the bars might provoke more ideas.

Comment: Your PDF is unavailable to the public, at least where I sit.

Comment: I have never _not_ had chipping like that on ceramic tile cuts, but I've never tried to eliminate it.  I just assumed that was unavoidable.

Comment: Link is broken  for table saw

Comment: It is this one here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iVLhWUZbdQ&ab_channel=badboy3985  funny thing this guy is pushing (actually pulling it) the the other way. I was pushing the saw from right to left. Here is the manual, another link https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1247344/Mastercraft-055-6740-2.html?page=10

Comment: Both tiles look chipped. I believe it is standard practice to place cut edges along the wall so that baseboard will cover the imperfections. Aside from that try feeding the material slower; like pretend some BMW is tailgating you while you're already doing 75 and want to teach them a lesson.

Comment: Teach him a lesson, @MonkeyZeus, by getting out of the left lane and letting _him_ get pulled over. Or, possibly, he's got someone sick in the car and is trying to get them to a doctor. Or, he's just a jerk and your "lesson" won't do any good at all. :/

Comment: @FreeMan I'm referring to the ones casually leaned back and usually texting on a single-lane double-lined road.

Comment: have you tried cutting the tile with the backside facing up? You may need to dress the diamond blade and/or push slower as well

Answer (score 5):

On a sliding bridge saw like this, it is important to ensure that the plane of the blade is accurately parallel to the sliding guides. If it isn't parallel, the back of the blade removes additional material from one side of the cut, and because it is moving upwards it is more likely to cause chipping.

Comment: That kid of makes sense but if this is the case, watching what happens on that side of the cut should show me that for most of the lenght of the cut that is where the blade is positioned at a certain moment the cut is fine till the rear of the blade reaches  that area at which pornt it starts ruining it. Ok I will check this tomorrow. I guess one way to measure it is to check the distance from the front and the rear of the blade  to one of the edges  of the cutting bed. I did that but my reference was the middle point of the blade where it is be the lowest point of the cutting bed)

Comment: @MiniMe You can make small adjustments by loosening the four screws holding the saw body to the sleigh handle, twisting and then retightening the screws. The needed adjustment is probably a fraction of a millimeter.  I have the same model as the diagram you added.  If you can't fully eliminate the chipping,  you can usually arrange for the side of the cut with more chips to be the waste piece.

Comment: I upgraded the device to cut 24x24 tiles...in the process I removed the screws that adjust the 0 degree point at each end ..I put them back yesterday and calibrated the thing. I also re aligned the fences to be square with the blade and I hope that now the blade is square with the tile. I am doing this outside because now the water pours outside of the tray when the tile is that large and the weather was bad yeaterday...hope to finalize the adjustments today and test to see if it is fixed

Comment: I was thinking the blade was not true with the guide also.+

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the tile is being fed at a slight bias. This can result in one side of the cutting edge of the blade working differently on the cut edge of the tile. It can also result in tearout at the *rear* of the blade due to dragging.

Check wither the feed motion of your table aligns perfectly with the position of the saw blade.

Comment: This is what they call a bridge wet saw....the blade moves over the tile, the tile sits on the cutting bed

Comment: The concept is the same. Is the fence aligned with the blade?

Comment: Not sure what you call the fence in this case, I have attached two pictures to the question, showing the tile saw and a representation of what I think it is happening

Comment: The fence is whatever device or gizmo that you use to align the tile. Don't overthink it. :)

Comment: I think @Stephen below is right the blade needs to be parallel with the bars that support the linear move of the cut saw aligning the tile with the blade won't do much

Comment: Yep, and by doing so you align the blade with the fence or guide. It's all symptoms of the same principle. Good luck.

Comment: Ironically, @MiniMe, your drawing _shows_ the blade badly misaligned with the cut. Make sure it isn't also that way in real life.